# Update a HTML table in Python

Tags: python, html

I am a novice coder. I have a HTML table that looks like this and is dynamically created by a python script.

```
  A B C D E F
G 1 1 0 0 1 1
H 1 0 1 2 4 5
```

Here is the code that generates this table:

```
f.write("<center><table align = 'center' border=\"1\" width=\"800\" height=\"40\"><tr><td align = 'center'><h3><b>Compared TaskLogs</h3></td><td align = 'center'><h3><b>Total</h3></td><td align = 'center'><h3><b>Passed</h3></td><td colspan = '3' align = 'center'><h3><b>Bug</h3></td><td align = 'center' colspan ='3'><h3><b>Script</h3></td><td align = 'center' colspan = '3'><h3><b>Setup</h3></td></tr></b>");
f.write("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td>")
f.write("<td align = 'center'><h5><b>Known</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Unknown</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Total</b></h5>")
f.write("<td align = 'center'><h5><b>Known</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Unknown</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Total</b></h5>")
f.write("<td align = 'center'><h5><b>Known</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Unknown</b></h4></td><td align = 'center'><h5><b>Total</b></h5>")
f.write("</tr>")

        if 'text' in s:
                    counter_pass=0;
                    counter_kbug=0;
                    counter_kscr=0;
                    counter_kset=0;
                    counter_uscr=0;
                    counter_ubug=0;
                    counter_uset=0;
                    totbug = 0;
                    totscr = 0;
                    totset = 0;
                    tottc=0;
                    for key, value in tlogs.items():
                            print"entering loop: for key, value in tlogs.items(): VALUE:",value
                            print "ITEM:",s
                            if (value==s):

                                    value1=tcstatus[key]
                                    print "VALUE--", value1
                                    if value1=="p":
                                            counter_pass=counter_pass+1;
                                    if value1=="kbug":
                                            counter_kbug=counter_kbug+1;
                                    if value1=="kscr":
                                            counter_kscr=counter_kscr+1;
                                    if value1=="kset":
                                            counter_kset=counter_kset+1;
                                    if value1=="ubug":
                                            counter_ubug=counter_ubug+1;
                                    if value1=="uscr":
                                            counter_uscr=counter_uscr+1;
                                    if value1=="uset":
                                            counter_uset=counter_uset+1;


                    totbug = counter_kbug+counter_ubug
                    totscr = counter_kscr+counter_uscr
                    totset = counter_kset+counter_uset
                    tot = counter_pass+totbug+totscr+totset
                    f.write("<tr><td height=\"30\"><a href="+st+"/table_"+item[4:]+".html>"+s[:-4]+"</a></td><td height=\"30\">"+str(tot)+"</a></td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_pass)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kbug)+"</td><td>"+str(counter_ubug)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totbug)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_uscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totscr)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_kset)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(counter_uset)+"</td><td height=\"30\">"+str(totset)+"</td></tr></center><br>");

f.write("</table></center></body>")
```

I have another text file that looks like this:

```
G,A
H,E
```

Now I need to update the table entry in the Gth row and Ath column by 1 and Hth row and Eth column by 1.

All this is done in python. Could someone help me please!

Comment: show us the code that generates this table

Comment: @WildCard5, I have added the code.